# Does the order of memory arguments in the Solidity function matter?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

i'm trying to make the simple storage using Solidity. Here I'm just trying to map name to some number.

The problem is the following: if I use `store_first()` it does not work (the `retrieve()` function returns 0 in any case). But if I change the order of the arguments and place the `string memory _name` before `uint256 _favoriteNumber` everything works (the `retrieve()` function returns correct number)

Does the problem relates to the order (if yes, why?) or I missed something else?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity >0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToNumber;

    // If i use this function, the retrieve function always returns 0
    function store_first(uint256 _favoriteNumber, string memory _name) public {
        nameToNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    // If i use this function, the retrieve function returns correct number
    function store_second(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        nameToNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve(string memory _name) public view returns(uint256){
        return nameToNumber[_name];
    }
}
```

Comment: `But if I change the order of the arguments` - have you made sure to also change the order of input values that you pass when you call this function?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb yes, I'm sure about the order of input values.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb okay It seems I solved this, the mistake was quite stupid: I used the following input "15, John". The thing is the space is part of the string and I completely forgot about it hahah